# difference between add_options and register_setting

Tags: plugins

I am confused. Want to save data for my plugin. There are people who use add_options and there are others who use register_settings. My question is What is difference between `add_options` and `register_setting`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[register_setting()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) uses [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), which is just an API for options.php, is easier to use, more secure and preffered way of storing options since WordPress 2.7.

If you need to store only a few options or doing simple plugin just for yourself - it's really up to you which one to use :)

Here's the Settings API (well) explained: http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/

Basically it makes a few things much easier, you don't have to render whole forms all over again (great for plugins/themes with many options), you don't need to care about nonces etc.

So, to sum up, both these functions actually do the same thing :)

Comment: an example, there you can use http://svn.wp-plugins.org/addquicktag/trunk/inc/class-settings.php